Json path not found
I'm running a simple feature with karate DSL version 1.5.0.RC3 and Java 17.
When I run the feature in Command Line: java -jar karate.jar src/test/resources/subdirectory/myfile.feature
But I get the following error: js failed:
01: read ('classpath:myData.json')
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found: myData.json
Here bellow the feature
@myproject
Feature: login user

  Background:

    
    * def req = read ('classpath:src/test/resources/subdirectory/myData.json')


  Scenario: Login User



    Given url 'https://myUrl'
    And path '/mypath/'
    And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
    And request req
    When method POST
    Then status 201

I'm expecting a status code 201

Maybe you should use file: instead of classpath:. Read the documentation to understand what they mean: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#path-prefixes
For completeness of this answer, note that when you run java you can modify the classpath.

Thank you @Peter Thomas! With 'file' it doesn't work but with 'this' it work

@NPGK great, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
